# I need a J2me datamatrix decoder library that is not Zxing

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, mobile-phones, nokia

I am writing an application that uses Zxing datamatrix decoder. It is OK for QR but not for datamatrix. It only decodes it if it is code-generated, absolutely clean. But if it is a captured-by-camera image it does not work well.

Is there an alternative to this library (for J2me)?

Comment: Nowadays, Zxing has improved and I am very glad about the results. Zxing is great!!

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the subject and it's very difficult to find libraries that decode Datamatrix.

Maybe you'll find this library interesting : [libdmtx](http://www.libdmtx.org/), it is written in C but you have a Java wrapper (informations on the [libdmtx wiki](http://libdmtx.wikidot.com/)).

I know that is not J2ME like you want but maybe you can find a way to create a J2ME wrapper with that or the Java wrapper could work with a J2ME project.

Hope this helps !

Comment: You cannot use the JNI with J2ME, which means you cannot load libraries written in other languages. The wrapper in Java is based on this. Thx.